# flask run not finding module import but works with gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

Having a module not found error ​when starting Flask like this:

`$ python src/app/main.py`

```
$ python src/app/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/james/code/webapp/src/app/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app.web import app_config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

Directory :

```
src
 |- app    
 |- |- __init__.py
 |- |- main.py
 |- |- web
 |- |- |- __init__.py
 |- |- |- app_config.py
```

main.py :

```
from flask import Flask

from app.web import app_config


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.get("/ping")
def ping():

    return "pong"

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run(debug=True)
```

But if I start it with gunicorn then it is fine:

```
$  gunicorn app.main:app
[2022-01-22 15:28:58 +0000] [148] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-01-22 15:28:58 +0000] [148] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (148)
[2022-01-22 15:28:58 +0000] [148] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-01-22 15:28:58 +0000] [150] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 150
```

Why is running Flask directly from terminal not letting it find higher level directory modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `app` module is not found because of the [Module Search Path of Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path). It tries to import from `main.py`'s directory.

If you don't want to change anything, `cd` into `src/` directory, and from there use the "module method" to run the app:

```
$ python -m app.main
```

Second method: change `from app.web import app_config` line to `from web import app_config`, then the original `python src/app/main.py` will work because now it imports relative from `main.py`.

Third option: add the full path of `src` directory to [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) env var.

Comment: thanks, this is concise and helpful. I am sure this answer will help many others with this issue.